# ant task send email - mail type doesn't support the nested "attachments" element

Tags: email, ant, task

Ant task send email - mail type doesn't support the nested "attachments" element.

I am using maven to run the test automation scripts using TestNG. I am using maven antrun plugin to send email with Test NG report in the attachement.

Unfortunately I can't sent email with attachement and getting error as

**Embedded error: The mail> type doesn't support the nested "attachments" element.**

here is my pom.xml

```
     <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <mail
                                    tolist=""
                                    from=""
                                    subject="Report"
                                    mailhost=""
                                    mailport=""
                                    user=""
                                    password="">
                                <message>Please find the Attached automation report.
                                      Note: This is an automatic generated e-mail
                                </message>
                                <attachments>
                                    <fileset dir="target">
                                        <include name="**/*.html"/>
                                    </fileset>
                                </attachments>
                            </mail>
                           </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <id>SentEmail</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven postman plugin worked fine for me. Thanks for you help.

```
  <plugin>
            <groupId>ch.fortysix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-postman-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>send a mail</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>send-mail</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <inherited>false</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <from>xxxxxxxx</from>
                        <subject>Regression Report</subject>
                        <failonerror>true</failonerror>
                        <mailhost>xxxxx</mailhost>
                        <mailport>xxx</mailport>
                        <mailuser>xxxxxx</mailuser>
                        <mailpassword>xxxxx</mailpassword>
                        <htmlMessage>Please find the Attached automation report.
                            Note: This is an automatic generated e-mail</htmlMessage>
                        <receivers>
                            <receiver>email@email.com</receiver>
                        </receivers>
                        <fileSets>
                            <fileSet>
                                <directory>${basedir}/target</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/emailable-report.html</include>
                                   <!-- <include>**/*.zip</include> -->
                                </includes>
                            </fileSet>
                        </fileSets>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the java activation framework and java mail jars to your
classpath.
They don't come with Ant or Java and can be downloaded [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html)

Download the 2 jars, add them to your ant classpath, and it should
work fine.

By the way, the Ant documentation [tells](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#librarydependencies) you about this on the manual
page for the [mail task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/mail.html).